# Timezone not setting on NSCalendar

Tags: ios, nscalendar, nstimezone

When I instantiate a simple NSCalendar and try to set the timezone, it doesn't seem to have any effect.  Am I missing something here?

```
  NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] init];
  NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Denver"];
  NSLog(@"tz:%@", tz);
  //outputs: tz:America/Denver (MST) offset -25200

  [cal setTimeZone: tz];
  NSLog(@"[cal timeZone]:%@", [cal timeZone]);
  //outputs: [cal timeZone]:(null)

  cal.timeZone = tz;
  NSLog(@"cal.timeZone:%@", cal.timeZone);
  //outputs: cal.timeZone:(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I guess you can't set a timezone on an NSCalendar object that was created with `[[NSCalendar alloc] init]`.  It should be `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]`.  The setter must be doing something fancy besides just writing the value and that doesn't work if it's not one of the preconfigured calendars.